# Cakephp simple button Click

Tags: cakephp, button

basically only having experience in .Net .
Here my problem is that in my current project the client need to add one button ( Book Now),it redirects to another ctp file .i have used one code but it is not working.Its just a static site and the previous developer doesnt used any model for the same.After several coding i used one code but now it is also not working.Help Me

```
enter code here
<tr>
  <td  style="margin-top: 15px;" colspan="3"><?php echo $form->submit('Book  Now',array('controller'=> 'home' ,'action'=>'booknow', 'style'=>'color:black;font:bold;width:160px;height:30px; margin-left:25px;margin-top:-15px;')); ?>  </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other action is some static page then you can use this

```
  <?php 
   echo $this->Html->link('Book Now', 
                               array(
                                    'controller'=> 'home' ,
                                    'action'=>'booknow',
                                    'style'=>'color:black;font:bold;width:160px;height:30px; margin-left:25px;margin-top:-15px;'
                                    )
                              ); 
   ?>
```

Of course you can style this link to look like button.

You don't need to use form helper for this purpose. All this is if you don't have any logic in your controller's action and do not need to send some data to that action.

Comment: Hello When i click on the Book Now Button it redirects but in address bar it shows that http://gagoinn.com/home/booknow/style:color:black;font:bold;width:160px;height:30px;%20margin-left:25px;margin-top:-15px;

Comment: Read this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html on how to style link, the 'style' in url array is not serving the right purpose.

Comment: Ohh Thank you... I just removed the style code and uploaded .Now its working fine